# cannot read property handleSetJSResponder of null error in react native v0.70.3

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I have updgraded my React Native version to 0.70.3 from 0.64.2 and accordingly upgraded the packages.

When running the debugging(react-native run-ios) for IOS, the above error is occurring on react-native-gesture-handler. If you have any method to fix this or any advice please share with me.

Added all the details(code,screenshots) to check in-detailed,Thanks in advance.

Please help me in reolving the issue by sharing the sample code or steps for resolving.

Below are the list of packages used in the project,

```
{
  "name": "projectSetup",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^9.2.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^6.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.5",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.8",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "^0.70.3",
    "react-native-android-location-enabler": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1275.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.2.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.1",
    "react-native-flexbox-grid": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.38.0",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.12",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.10.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-month-selector": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.5",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-signature-capture": "^0.4.12",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-sound-player": "^0.13.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-view-pdf": "^0.14.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

App.js code

```
import React from "react";
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, LogBox, TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";


class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={()=> {
                        Alert.alert('Hello...', 'kk')
                    }}
                    style={{height:200,backgroundColor:'red',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
                    <Text>Welcome Praveen</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

**ERROR [react-native-gesture-handler] react-native-gesture-handler module was not found. Make sure you're running your app on the native platform and your code is linked properly (cd ios && pod install && cd ..).

For installation instructions, please refer to https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/#installation**

Output of npx react-native-info

```
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: macOS 13.0
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8569U CPU @ 2.80GHz
    Memory: 37.48 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.10.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~/node_modules/.bin/yarn
    npm: 8.19.2 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.10.03.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 16.0, macOS 12.3, tvOS 16.0, watchOS 9.0
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9014738
    Xcode: 14.0.1/14A400 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.16.1 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: ^9.2.1 => 9.2.1 
    react: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0 
    react-native: ^0.70.3 => 0.70.4 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

install react-native-gesture-handler
then add react-native.config.js file in your root folder
add this code in it :

```
module.exports = {
project: {
ios: {},
android: {},
},
};
```

then run this command in your terminal
npx react-native-asset
now re-install your app

Comment: If you are not using expo, add this to your `metro.config.js`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error though I am using expo for my app.

My error was fixed by using a development build:

```
npx expo install expo-dev-client
```

Then I followed these docs to create my Android development build https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/

Answer (score 0):

Install `"react-native-gesture-handler"`

Then `import "GestureHandlerRootView"` and Wrap your main `NavigationContainer` Function Like below:

```js
<GestureHandlerRootView >

          <NavigationContainer>
            ...
    
          </NavigationContainer>

  </GestureHandlerRootView>
```